# In "La Haine" (1995 French movie), was this cop French or was he Arab?

Tags: character, la-haine

[image]

I was watching *La Haine*, and I thought he was Arab because of a comment Said made which at the time I initially misread, "An Arab wouldn't last one hour in a police station" (initially I read that as an Arab would not last in a career as a police officer a French police station), but then I realized he was referring to Arab victims of police brutality when I saw "hour."
So I'm wondering, is the cop who was sympathetic to the youth in the movie, French or Arab.
Said, one of the youth, is Arab, which leads me to believe, since the character is North Africa that he's Egyptian. But the cop, what is he?

Comment: The character us North African? If you identify the actor and his role we might be able to help. The most likely heritage is Algerian.

Comment: I mean the cop in the picture. He's right there

Comment: Obviously, but what is the character's name or the name of the actor?

Comment: The character. I know the answer now, because someone just told me, but I was wondering ethnically wise (cause I know nationality wise he's French), was he ethnic French or ethnic Arab...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plainclothes police officer is French as you need to be French to work for the French "Police Nationale". He is also Arab or Berber descent as the talk with Saïd indicates, and also his credit name *Samir*. He's most likely from francophonic North Africa (Tunisia, Morocco, Algeria). I wouldn't say Egypt since, even Egyptian immigration still existed, it was more rare.

He is portrayed by the French actor [**Karim Belkhadra**](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karim_Belkhadra) who is Kabyle.

So the cop is most likely French and North African Arab or North African Berber descent, not Asian Arab.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, bro :). I was wondering. So he is Arab. Just was a bit confused